# como faço para ler várias notícias, esta aparecendo somente a ultima

Tags: json

```
//CONEXAO COM O SEVIDOR DO SINDITAC E PEGAR O JSON COM AS NOTICIAS
$.getJSON("http://sinditac.siteseguro.ws/api/news.php?t=d18d31bd9b9f5f7b338e41b5986183a2f3008b541d7c84e442", function(data){
    // LER O JSON E INCLUIR NAS VARIAVEIS 
    for (i = 0; i < data.noticias.length; i++) {

        var  id ='';
        var titulo_breve = '';
        var titulo = '';
        var  noticia = '';
        var  imagem = '';
        var quem_cadastrou = '';
        var dt_cadastro = '';
        var dt_exclusao = '';

        id = data.noticias[i].id;
        titulo_breve = data.noticias[i].titulo_breve;
        titulo = data.noticias[i].titulo;
        noticia = data.noticias[i].noticia;
        imagem = data.noticias[i].imagem;
        quem_cadastrou = data.noticias[i].quem_cadastrou;
        dt_cadastro = data.noticias[i].dt_cadastro;
        dt_exclusao = data.noticias[i].dt_exclusao;


        // POPULAR O BANCO DE DADOS 
        conexao.transaction(function(tx){
            tx.executeSql('insert into noticias(titulo_breve, titulo, noticia, imagem, quem_cadastrou, dt_cadastro, dt_exclusao) values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)',[titulo_breve, titulo, noticia, imagem, quem_cadastrou, dt_cadastro, dt_exclusao],
            function(tx, res){
                console.log(res);
            });
        });
    }
});
}
```

Comment: como esta aparecendo somente uma, sendo que no json tem 10 ? no seu codigo nao exibe nada somente insere em uma tabela

Comment: aparece sim os 10 porém com a mesma informação, repetindo todas noticias da 1 a 10 com a mesma informação

Comment: os 10 aparece somente a ultima noticia que foi colocada no site

Comment: ate tentei fazer um teste mas como tem cors habilitado nao consegui tao rapido

Comment: Caso alguém consiga me ajudar , por favor preciso bastante..